# ruby using mod with switch

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a hash for a deck of cards, but  I can't get my when to work for when to make it an ace. None of my key's show up as aces, still working on JQK.  Apparently I don't understand how the switch in ruby works.

```
def generateDeck
  d1 = Hash.new
  ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'].each do |suite|
    case suite
    when 'D'
      loopStart = 14
      loopEnd   = 26
    when 'H'
      loopStart = 27
      loopEnd   = 39
    when 'S'
      loopStart = 40
      loopEnd   = 52
    else    
      loopStart = 1
      loopEnd   = 13
    end # of switch

    loopStart.upto(loopEnd) do |loop|
      puts("CurrentLoop: #{loop}")
      puts("Should Be Ace: #{loop % 13 == 1}")

      case loop
      when (loop % 13 == 1)
        d1['A' + suite] = loop
      when 11
        d1['J' + suite] = loop
      when 12
        d1['Q' + suite] = loop
      when 13
        d1['K' + suite] = loop
      else
        d1["#{loop}#{suite}"] = loop
      end # of switch
    end # of do
  end # of do

  d1['JA'] = 53
  d1['JB'] = 54
  return d1
end # of generateDecks

d1 = generateDeck
```

Comment: It's unusual to see `Hash.new` used without arguments. `{ }` is almost always used instead.

Comment: I'm new to ruby, do they mean different things?

Comment: It's the same as JavaScript, where `{ }` creates a new, empty hash. It's more concise and conventional. Same with `[ ]` being preferable to `Array.new`.

Comment: Thanks, { } looks better anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simpler ways to generate a deck of cards, but to make your method work, your second case statement needs to be modified. Since you start at 1 and go to 52 in your various loops, every thirteenth card will be an King, so whenever `x % 13 == 0`. You can make the same statements about the other face cards, e.g. Jack: `x % 13 == 11`. Aces are `x % 13 == 1`. The common test is `x % 13`, so that's what you put after `case`:

```
case loop % 13 
when 1
  d1['A' + suite] = loop
when 11
  d1['J' + suite] = loop
when 12
  d1['Q' + suite] = loop
when 0
  d1['K' + suite] = loop
else
  d1["#{loop % 13}#{suite}"] = loop
end
```

Since you asked, here's a simpler version. This iterates over two collections - suits and card values - and inserts each combination into a hash:

```
deck = {"JA" => 53, "JB" => 54}
%w(C D S H).each_with_index do |suit, s_index|
  %w(A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K).each_with_index do |card, c_index|
    deck["#{card}#{suit}"] = 13 * s_index + 1 + c_index
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd be interested in simpler ways, I'm going to try all the Ruby Quiz's to help learn ruby.  However I tried the changes and everything looks except my first ace.  It doesn't end up in the table and the first entry is "2C"=>1

Comment: I guess I assumed you wanted the cards numbered 1 through 52. What value should 2C have?

Comment: I was going to use with A, 2, 3, etc, to follow http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz1.html.

Comment: Thank you very much, your version looks much more concise.